# Excluding _id from Meteor search query?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to pull a document from a Meteor collection without the _id field but neither inclusion:

```
Db.find({foo: bar}, {fields: {
  test1: 1,
  test2: 1,
  _id: 0
}})
```

nor exclusion:

```
Db.find({foo: bar}, {fields: {
  test3: 0,
  _id: 0
}})
```

seem to work. Both just return an empty array. I know pulling a document with the _id excluded is possible in Mongo, is it in Meteor?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have forgotten some braces:

```
Db.find({
    foo: bar
}, {
    fields: {
        test3: 0,
        _id: 0
     }
});
```

And i have read somewhere, that the **mix of inclusion/exclusion is not supported**. This means, that your first example will not work.

**EDIT:**

From the meteor [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers):

> **Field Specifiers**
>
> On the server, queries can specify a particular set of fields to
>   include or exclude from the result object. (*The field specifier is
>   currently ignored on the client.*)
>
> To exclude certain fields from the result objects, the field specifier
>   is a dictionary whose keys are field names and whose values are 0.
>
> `Users.find({}, {fields: {password: 0, hash: 0}})`
>
> To return an object that only includes the specified field, use 1 as
>   the value. **The _id field is still included in the result.**
>
> `Users.find({}, {fields: {firstname: 1, lastname: 1}})`
>
> *It is not possible to mix inclusion and exclusion styles.*

Comment: Ya, but the thing is that neither of them work, which is strange since both do in MongoDb (or their equivalent, syntax is obviously slightly different)

Comment: I noticed that in the documentation, but to me the bolded part is a little vague and I don't think directly answers my question. I read it as saying that when selecting fields by explicitly stating which to include, the _id will still be included even if not mentioned, a property unique to it alone. To me that doesn't imply that it's necessarily impossible to exclude the _id by using different commands (such as explicitly stating to exclude it, although this seems to be the case). If it is impossible it's a bit odd, and if it's an intentional feature of Meteor I'd be curious as why it is.